# How to reopen last view while open the app after terminating in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am very new in iOS application development so don't have any special idea about the resources available in iOS development. 
I want that if I am on a particular view and then I suddenly terminate the app by clicking on "Home" button, then while I open the app again, it should open the last page on which I was while terminating the app. Since the app is not terminated, it was in background.

I can show the snapshot of my storyboard if it can describe my question in a better way-

[image]

In the screenshot, when I open the app after closing it, if I am not logged in then when I will open the app, Login screen (1) will open. And if I am logged in then (4) will open. That is correct. But suppose if I was on (5) before closing the app, then also it opens (4), that should not happen. How to control that?

If someone have any idea about that, please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see reference here

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=208

and here

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

And here

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios%20restore%20state%20stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the references, I hope it will help me in what I want to do. I will read that articles which you have shared.