# Saving Array to userDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift3, nsuserdefaults

My Requirement is user has to navigate  last visited page so

I am trying to save array of **UIViewController** to **NSUserDefault** but app is crashing every time

```
let array = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "LastNavigationArray")
```

For this try crash is

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
```

Also, I have tried with following code but no luck

```
let array = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)

UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "LastNavigationArray")
```

For this crash is

```
Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UIColor.m:1549
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation.'
```

If this is wrong please suggest me the correct way to implement it. 
Because I have very complex navigation flow.

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with your saving of array as per logs

Comment: @kapsym  NO it is crashing with same log

Comment: @kapsym Do you want me to put whole stack trace ?

Comment: I suppose that only RGBA or White color spaces are supported in this situation. It'd be so helpful, if Apple gave you hints in their crash logs...

Comment: @MikeAlter If you just want to save the VC where the user was last, can you just save the identifier. Any reason to save entire Viewcontrollers to user defaults?

Comment: @kapsym I have very complex Navigation flow , A Single screen can be appear on 7th position and one other scenario appears on 12th position on navigation. as i was thinking same but it is too complex and hard to modify on later time

Comment: Are all of your UIViewControllers inside the array implementing custom NSCoding ?

Comment: @Larme  No they are not

Comment: Then I'm not sure at all that they'll we recreated as such saved.

Comment: @Larme What would be a possible solution .?

Comment: We cannot store VC array in this manner.... But the question is why you need this to store in userdefaults because you always have this access by self.navigation in all VC

Comment: @MoinShirazi this for re open app

Comment: You may be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381127/how-to-reopen-last-view-while-open-the-app-after-terminating-in-ios But usually we don't really want to keep the whole hierarchy, just the last one maybe. It's too heavy to save (all has to be NSCoding compliant, etc. if there are HTTP requests, it's a nightmare, saving all the states, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

UIViewControllers are really heavy objects to save in UserDefaults.

You can keep a custom object for yourself to identify all the view controllers in navigation stack. For example you can construct a custom string with each individual view controller's class name strings. Or, a better option would be only store last view controller's class name in user defaults. You can instantiate and present that view controller by checking the class name when user opens your app again.